# Chausath Yogini Sadhana : 64 Yogini

Tags: durga, kali, shakta

Could someone refer me to which Hindu texts explain the details of how to perform Chausath Yogini Sadhana ?

There is a lot for this on social media sites, but not sure where they’re getting their info from. Not sure it’s supported by proper Hinduism texts.

Comment: Chatupshashti Yogini sadhana is like walking on rope. A single step of misplaced vidhi and it's rocking the cradle. Untill one has a Guru, it shall toss the person's life. Focus on one deity, stick to that deity for 4-5 years, and then it shall bear fruits. The whole online cult is bogus with zero spiritual zeal. It sounds fancy hearing such names like Yogini and Guhya, etc but it's dreadful. Please refrain from falling trap to all these.

Comment: @Chamundadas Thanks, yeah, I’ve found some info in different places, some online and some in person. I’m hoping to find the right guidance or mentor-ship eventually, but the city I’m in is full of fake guru types unfortunately. Though this is how it is everywhere nowdays.

Comment: No offense, but there are hidden gems amidst these fake gurus and they better keep low profile. If one can find upasakas in a hustling city like Mumbai, it's not hard to find guru in other places. Just, let the right time approach. Guru will himself walk down to u with his/her grace

Comment: @Chamundadas Thank you, yeah,